# Software for monitoring and measuring GPU temperature (Windows XP/7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, temperature, gpu

Are there any programs available for monitoring and measuring GPU temperature? I'd prefer something free, and for either Windows XP or Windows 7.

Comment: I've removed the second part. At the moment I just need the software.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/207850/recommend-a-free-temperature-monitoring-utility-for-cores-video-card-on-vista

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the makers of CPU-Z: [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html). Small, free, and can measure video card GPU temperatures.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

CPUZ http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php is a free utility for such things. Also GPUZ http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/ is good too, for graphic cards.

Comment: Used both software before. Unless I'm mistaken, CPU-Z is more for processors (CPUs) and GPU-Z doesn't really provide GPU temperature. But your link did lead me to HWMonitor, so +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Dell Precision, an excellent utility is the [Dell fan control utility](http://www.diefer.de/i8kfan/). It's got tray icons, graphs, manual and automatic fan speed adjustments, ...

Comment: This also appears to be something for CPUs only. I need something for the video card (GPU), not the CPU.

Answer (score -1):

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) monitors hardware and can read values such as temperatures, fan speeds, voltages, etc.

[image]