# Live update CPU temperature in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, cpu, temperature

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Software for monitoring/measuring GPU temperature (WinXP/7)](https://superuser.com/questions/118766/software-for-monitoring-measuring-gpu-temperature-winxp-7)
>   [Good software for measuring computer temperature?](https://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature)

I was wondering how to get live update of CPU temperature in Windows XP. Any recommendations for such softwares?

I have heard that [Everest](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Everest-Home-Edition.shtml) is one choice. But after I installed it, I don't find it provides constantly-updating CPU temperature but only static value in its user interface (under computer -> sensor), neither does it show the temperature as tray icon after minimizing its user interface.
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, if you think it is duplicate, then you must know what software can live update CPU temperature and also can sit as a tray icon?

Comment: If you don't know the answer to my question, then how can you claim it is duplicate??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) for this in the past. Will give you temperatures and also can site in the tray w/ current temp(s) displayed.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the difference between Temp1 and Core shown in SpeedFan? Whose temperature is more important?

Comment: Generally, the "core" temps are the ones you would care the most about as that's the processor core itself (or multiples for many multi-core procs). Other reported temps could include chipsets, ambient case temps, video cards and even drives.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a very handy software : **Speccy** by Piriform software company. This software not only shows the live update of CPU temperature but also many other utilities like hard drive temperature, graphics and motherboard information. It is basically a system information utility written for Windows platform. You can get it here:
[Speccy by Piriform](http://www.piriform.com/speccy)

All the best.

Comment: Is Speccy live updating CPU temperature? I don't see this on the webpage.

Comment: Did you download it and use it? After installing it just click the bar near the temperature it shows. It would show the progress of the temperature like how the performance is shown in task manager.

Comment: I did not because it is not free...

Comment: It is a freeware. Check it out at filehippo in the following link: http://www.filehippo.com/download_speccy/