# Temperature monitor software

Tags: temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for monitoring and measuring GPU temperature (Windows XP/7)](https://superuser.com/questions/118766/software-for-monitoring-and-measuring-gpu-temperature-windows-xp-7)

I am looking for a good software that measures the CPU temperature and the GPU temperature, but one software for both, now I am using 2 different software for that.

what do you recommend ?

thank you

Comment: What OS? You should tag your question with the OS you are concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

[HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/hwmonitor/1.19-setup.exe) is a hardware monitoring program that reads PC systems main health sensors : voltages, temperatures, fans speed.

It can read modern CPUs on-die core thermal sensors, as well has hard drives temperature via S.M.A.R.T, and video card GPU temperature.

[image]