# Is it possible to monitor CPU Temperature with Windows Performance Monitor?

Tags: windows, system-monitoring

I would like to take a baseline of a system for CPU, CPU Temperature, Hard Drive Reads/Writes, Page File, and Memory.  I did not see a counter for the CPU Temperature in the Windows 7 Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe).  Is it possible?  Thanks.

Comment: If you don't see a counter then you can assume it not a feature of WPM.  You will have to use some other program for the missing measurements.

Comment: If you have an Intel CPU take a look at: http://www.intel.com/software/pcm

Comment: or HWMonitor: http://superuser.com/questions/118766/software-for-monitoring-and-measuring-gpu-temperature-windows-xp-7. But I guess Ramhound is right: If its not in the list, it isn't supported :-/